# Sort List<Object> with Duplicates by grabbing the one with the most recent date

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects that contain (ID, Date). There are cases where there will be duplicate IDS, but with different dates. Both of these are strings.

I need to sort the list by getting the ID and most recent date, while removing the older date.

Example

```
ID: 1 Date 1-1-2018
ID: 1 Date: 1-1-2019
```

I have tried using the code below.

```
unsortedList.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(record => Convert.ToDateTime(record.Date)));
```

I am still seeing the Ids in the original form.

```
public class Record
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: added class like someone asked

Comment: How are you assigning`unsortedList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you had left to do was grab the first result of each ordered group.

```
var filteredList = unsortedList.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(group => group
        .OrderByDescending(record => Convert.ToDateTime(record.Date))
            .First());
```

Comment: you are a genius thanks I had a mistake on my end somehow your code works